# How to update npm package's dependency?

Tags: npm, dependencies, package.json

I am trying to update dependency of package I am installing trough `npm`.

When I install `appium` package, I get version `1.22.0` which is correct. But this package also have dependencies that getting regular updates on github and are propagated on npmjs.

But when I install main package, dependency is not latest.

For example, I need to update `appium-espresso-driver` dependency of `appium` to `1.50.1`, but everytime I install `appium`, dependency is only `1.45.3`, even when `appium` have `^1.0.0` in `package.json`

How to update this? Do I need to wait for `appium` package to be bumped?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update all the packages to the latest version and you are using **npm**, you can see this documentation [npm-update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-update), but the short answer is:

`npm update`

This helps to update every package of the project, you can do it in the root folder, and update everything in the `package.json`.

If you want to update everything to a latest version, you can use `npm-check-updates`, this will check the latest version of the packages that you have installed on `package.json`, I will show you the easy steps to install this but you can go through the documentation of the module in [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates):

- `npm install -g npm-check-updates`

This will install you the package, then after that you need to run in in the root folder:

- `ncu -u`

So after that command it will update all the packages in the `package.json` but not install them, so after running `ncu -u` you need to run again:

- `npm install`

To install the new versions of the package.

Comment: Also if you are using `yarn` in the future (because is a lot better to work with), you have this link: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/

Comment: I tried that.. It does not work.. Package's dependencies are still same...

Comment: If you want to update everything to be UPDATED to a stable version, you should use always `npm update`, I didn't get what you were saying, now I get it because you want to update to the latest version, you can check again my comment, I will edit it, this will update everything to the latest version (not stable), just latest.

Comment: I was checking also the versions of that package, and I don't see any version of `1.50.1`,  but I saw the  `npm i appium@2.0.0-beta.19` this should be the latest version but is still in beta

Comment: It is package `appium-espresso-driver` what is dependency of `appium`. Thats what got updated and what I need to get.

Comment: @Wesler `yarn upgrade` does not update the version in package.json, it updates `yarn.lock` based on whatever version range is specified in `package.json`. You'll want to use `yarn add <package> [--latest/other options]`.